# PHP Mysql - adding an empty row can't figure it out

Tags: mysql

Here is the table code - when this is printed out the has one empty row at the bottom.  I am not sure why the last row is added?  Is it perhaps the if else statement?

```
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($row['Price'] == '0.00') {
echo "<TABLE  width='100%'>\n";
echo "<TR><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Item</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Size</TD><TD  
id=tblrowsHead2>Contact</TD></TR>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //get a row from our result set
    if ($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
        echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\">\n";
    } else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
        echo "<TR bgcolor=\"white\">\n";
    }
    echo "<TD id=Size>" . $row['Item'] . "</TD><TD id=Size>" . $row['Size'] 
. "</TD> 
<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD>\n";

}
} else {
echo "<TABLE  width='100%'>\n";
echo "<TR><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Item</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Size</TD><TD  
id=tblrowsHead2>Price</TD></TR>\n";
for ($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //get a row from our result set
    if ($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
        echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\">\n";
    } else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
        echo "<TR bgcolor=\"white\">\n";
    }
    echo "<TD id=Size>" . $row['Item'] . "</TD><TD id=Size>" . $row['Size'] 
. "</TD> 
<TD id=Price>$" . $row['Price'] . "</TD>\n";

}
}

//now let's close the table and be done with it
echo "</TABLE>\n";
?>
```

Comment: what is the result HTML?

Comment: <TR bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<TD id=Size>Pillow sham</TD><TD id=Size>Continental</TD>
<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD>
<TR bgcolor="white">
<TD id=Size>Cushion</TD><TD id=Size>Breakfast</TD>
<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD>
<TR bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<TD id=Size>Cushion</TD><TD id=Size>Neckroll</TD>
<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD>
<TR bgcolor="white">
<TD id=Size>Cushion</TD><TD id=Size>Toss</TD>
<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD>
<TR bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<TD id=Size></TD><TD id=Size></TD>
<TD id=Price></TD>
</TABLE>

Comment: You are trying to execute html in php if you want to do that you have to intercept the php with a ?> before you state a html thing and once html is stated continiue with the php tag with <?php

Comment: Thanks Tomm appreciate the help - not quite sure I follow you though.  I thought I was injecting the HTML after the php tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
<?php

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$i = 0;
if ($row['Price'] == '0.00') {
    echo "<TABLE  width='100%'>\n";
    echo "<TR><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Item</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Size</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Contact</TD></TR>\n";
    do {
        if ($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
            echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\">\n";
        } else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
            echo "<TR bgcolor=\"white\">\n";
        }
        echo '<TD id=Size>'.$row['Item'].'</TD><TD id=Size>'.$row['Size'].'</TD>';
        echo "<TD id=Price>Contact Us</TD></TR>\n";
        $i++;
    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); //get a row from our result set
} else {
    do {
        if ($i % 2) { //this means if there is a remainder
            echo "<TR bgcolor=\"#E6E6FA\">\n";
        } else { //if there isn't a remainder we will do the else
            echo "<TR bgcolor=\"white\">\n";
        }
        echo '<TD id=Size>'.$row['Item'].'</TD><TD id=Size>'.$row['Size'].'</TD>';
        echo "<TD id=Price>$" . $row['Price'] . "</TD></TR>\n";
        $i++;
    } while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)); //get a row from our result set
}
//now let's close the table and be done with it
echo "</TABLE>\n";
```

When you using the **mysql_fetch_array** at the first line of **for-loop**, you will lost the first record of your data-table, so you will have an empty line at the end

Comment: @MichaelDeBeer i dont understand why you just checked the first record's price, but its your choice. I mean if you want to write down "Contact Us" for zero prices, you need to check it inside the loop.

Comment: That works like a charm - thank you - missed the "    echo "<TABLE  width='100%'>\n";
    echo "<TR><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Item</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Size</TD><TD id=tblrowsHead2>Contact</TD></TR>\n";" on the else - but once I added that - it works.  Again thank you